# useEffect to occur multiple times

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I want the useEffect to occur multiple times. For example in the below example, everything works correctly the first time round.

If the input field is empty, and you click on 'Next', the focus then shifts to another button. When you click this button, the focus then shifts to the incomplete question. However this only works on the first render. How do I get it to work so that the useEffect occurs each time the button is clicked?

https://codepen.io/theinteractivedom/pen/ZExpqBy

```
const Summary = () => {
  const [hasErrors, setHasErrors] = useState(false);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const goToQuestionButton = useRef();
  const inputRef = useRef();

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (message.trim().length !== 0) {
      console.log("input value is NOT empty");
    } else {
      setHasErrors(true);
    }
  };

  const handleClickTwo = () => {
    inputRef.current.focus();
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setMessage(event.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasErrors === true) {
      goToQuestionButton.current.focus();
    }
  }, [hasErrors]);

  return (
    <div className='questions'>
      <p>What is your name?</p>
      <input
        onChange={handleChange}
        ref={inputRef}
        id="firstName"
        name="firstName"
      ></input>
      <button onClick={handleClickTwo} ref={goToQuestionButton}>
        Go to incomplete question
      </button>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Next</button>
    </div>
  );
```

};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useEffect` will trigger any time the value of `hasErrors` *changes*. You never reset the `hasErrors` value after the input is focused.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (hasErrors === true) {
      goToQuestionButton.current.focus();
      setHasErrors(false);
    }
  }, [hasErrors]);
```

Setting `hasErrors` to false after focusing the question will reset everything and allow it to be triggered again the next time `hasErrors` is set to true.

Answer (score 1):

The useEffect always triggers, when the state in the dependency array changes. If you set the state on true again, it does not change. Therefore, the useEffect is not triggered. You have to setHasErrors(false) after resolving the error or focusing the question Button.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you have `[hasErrors]` as a dependency for useEffect. That means that `useEffect` will only run if `hasErrors` changes. Right now you are only changing `hasErrors` to false in `handleClick`. On subsequent clicks, it is still false so useEffect doesn't think anything changed and therefore doesn't run. If you want it to run depending on `hasErrors`, you will need to keep changing `hasErrors` back and forth from true to false. But since inside `useEffect` you are checking for false only, you could instead just remove the dependency and let `useEffect` run every single render, like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasErrors === true) {
      goToQuestionButton.current.focus();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move `goToQuestionButton.current.focus()` inside `handleClick` function and remove from useEffect. like this:

```
    const handleClick = () => {
        if (message.trim().length !== 0) {
          console.log("input value is NOT empty");
        } else {
          setHasErrors(true);
          goToQuestionButton.current.focus()
        }
      };
     useEffect(() => {

     }, [hasErrors]);
```